# Can I use a normal wifi adapter instead of a alfa card for evil twin attack?

Tags: network

I am new to security and more leaned on application security. But now I learning attacks like the evil twin I need an wifi adapter (correct me if I am wrong ) to do the attack. 
 I live in a remote country to the South and Alfa cards are hard to get around here. (do not ask me why)... The question is can I buy a normal wifi adapter and use it with the same functionality as an Alfa card knowing it will be different in terms of efficiency and signal capability just to understand and learn the evil twin attack and so on?
I ask because I had only one wlan interface on my Kali Linux and cannot use it to set up a for AP... Should I obliged to buy an exact Alfa card for this or wifi adapter should be good enough?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The external Alfa wifi adapters are recommended because they use wi-fi chipsets that support all the necessary operations (e.g. packet injection and monitor mode) that are required for full use of the aircrack-ng suite, and the latest Kali distros support them out of the box without much faffing around.

[This reply](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/76983/what-is-the-need-and-purpose-of-packet-injection-within-wifi-attacks) explains it more fully.

Comment: But just for this attack (evil twin) can I use a normal adapter?

Comment: No, these attacks require that chipset functionality. Is why they are recommended. What you can do, however, is find out if your chipset is capable of those modes. Be aware though, that this kind of activity *can* burn out your wifi chip (have done so before a few times), so it's better to do that with an external, easily replaceable one :)